# How to determine type of the document (Word or Excel) by its content

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I'm using Open XML Format SDK 2.0 to work with Word and Excel documents. I need a possibility to determine type of the document (Word or Excel) by its content, without creating the instances `WordprocessingDocument` or `SpreadsheetDocument`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unzip the docx, xlsx or whatever Microsoft Office document you want to check and then look at the tag

```
<Application>Microsoft Office Word</Application>
```

in the **app.xml** file you can find in the docProps folder. In case it's a .net 4.5 application you can use the new **ZipArchive** class to extract the xml file in-memory and then lookup the Application Tag.

You can find more details about the internal structure of a Office document in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb264572%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you JamesBond, this is a good solution, but it is very expensive for me. I found simple soultion, base on doc content: (data.Count() > 1 && data[0] == 0x50 && data[1] == 0x4B). But there is no difference between Word and Excel.

Comment: What's less expensive than extracting a small xml file out of a zip file and all in-memory?

Comment: My app based on .NET 3.5, so I haven't got usefull zip classes.

Comment: But I'm not sure I've understood you correctly. Is your problem now solved with this data.Count() approach you've mentioned or not yet?

Comment: Yes, I know about dotnetzip. and I try your solution. My problem is not solved with data.Count(), because first some bytes are equal in 'Word' and 'Excel' docs. Thank you JamesBond.